# php Preg_replace - turning a matching word in a database into a local url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Assume in the below code that there is a match for #bob and #test, **what would be the preg_replace expression so that #bob and #to are urls (ie http://test.com/read.php?id=bob)**? Note there is no hashtag in the id=bob part.

```
$text = "my name is #bob and I like #to #test things.";

preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $text, $matches);

foreach($matches['0'] as $match){

$substring = substr($match, 1);


$titlerows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT title FROM title WHERE title='$substring'"));

if($titlerows == 1) {

    $text = preg_replace('/$match/', replace?? , $text);

}

}

echo $text;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a question.

Comment: I have problems as well to decipher this.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` if you don't do an efficient `title IN (..)` lookup anyway.

Comment: what you get when you print_r($matches);

Comment: @FeRtoll Array ( [0] => #bob [1] => #to [2] => #test )

Comment: now i am confused a bit :D what is a problem actually? you want to replace #bob and #to in $text with URL+id=bob?

Comment: @FeRtool yes that what's im tryin to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like FeRtoll's answer, but this takes advantage of the fact that we already did the `substr()` earlier:

```
$text = preg_replace("/$match/", "http://test.com/read.php?id=.$substring", $text);
```

For the more complex replacement in the comment, do:

```
$text = preg_replace("/$match/", "<a href='http://test.com/read.php?id=$substring'>$match</a>", $text);
```

I like interpolation rather than concatenation.

Comment: Thanks. How would i correctly do the below:

`$text = preg_replace("/$match/", '<a href="http://test.com/read.php?id='.$substring">.$match.'</a>' , $text);`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you, if i understood your question good.

```
$text = preg_replace('/'.$match.'/', 'http://test.com/read.php?id='.substr($match,1) , $text);
```

EDITED:

```
$text = preg_replace("/$match/", '<a href="http://test.com/read.php?id='.$substring.'">'.$match.'</a>' , $text);
```

Comment: This cannot possibly work. The pattern `$match` tries to match `match` **after** the end of the string. When using single-quoted strings no replacement of variables is done.

Comment: @m.buettner What would be the correct expression then?

Comment: @Anonymous I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. Your question isn't clear at all, unfortunately.

Comment: @m.butettner 

Lets assume $match = '#test'

$text = my name is #bob and I like #to #test things.

I want to make it so $match is a hyperlink like: http://test.com/read.php?id='.substr($match,1)

Comment: @Anonymous well, try double quoted strings for the pattern `"/$match/"`. Note that I'm not saying this is the way you should do it. Using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is probably the way to go, but I don't have the time, to put an answer together

Comment: i have edited the answer, like this it should work.

Comment: @FeRtoll Thanks. How would i correctly do the below: 

`$text = preg_replace("/$match/", '<a href="http://test.com/read.php?id='.$substring">.$match.'</a>' , $text);`